# eclipse setting to auto rename class files

Tags: java, eclipse

I am looking for a setting in eclipse, where, if I right click and rename the file, then the content of the file as well gets changed to mirror the new name.

Say I had a class called

```
public ClasA{

}
```

I right click the file called ClasA.java and rename it to ClassA.java. I would like my class in the source file to be renamed as follows

```
public ClassA{

}
```

The same with packages as well.
If I change the location of a source file to a different package, I would like the `package sourcecode.location;` as well to change accordingly.

For some reason, I'm having to rename this in the current eclipse. Can someone tell me where the setting is.

Answer (score 5):

Press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to Refactor. Please check [Eclipse documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_rename.htm) for more options.

Comment: Hmm, I remember Eclipse doing it automatically if I were to rename files. Is there a setting for that, was my question.

Comment: @learningboy If you rename the file *outside* Eclipse, then Refresh in Eclipse, it'll see the problem and tell you. Then press ctrl+1 to show the Quick Fix menu and select the appropriate action.

Comment: @Andreas it doesn't show me in the Quick Fix. However, it looks like I had a configuration in my previous eclipse, where it would fix these issues automatically without having to right click and ask it to do the suggested fix.

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut for renaming is <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. You can rename any class, method, or variable and Eclipse will update all places where it is used.

To get used to it at first you can Right Click -> Refactor (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>). It will show you the options like renaming, moving package, etc. Any action done through that many will update all corresponding references in your project.